# Is there a page or document which ALL Windows APIs sorted alphabet order?

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn

Sometimes, I want to find a function by guessing a function name.

I can't this at MSDN.

Is there a good web page or a document?

Comment: Are there several Windows APIs? You probably mean "ALL *functions* of the Windows API".

Comment: You're right. It means "ALL functions of the Windows API"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download the Windows SDK, then you get the "Windows SDK Documentation" as a local/compiled help file: in which the "Index" is sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

About the closest I can think of is [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net), which is written from a C#/PInvoke perspective, but lists all the function exports from a number of Windows DLLs.

The main problem is that the list is *enormous*. I would say google is actually the best option...